# Efficiency : link between tables

Tags: mysql

I use this simplified MYSQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE element (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 text varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 text varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I want to link both database with another one :

**OPTION 1**

```
CREATE TABLE assoc_element_tags (
 elem_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 tag_id int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

I was wondering what are the drawback of doing this instead, for easier "text" access :
Here "elem_text" is equal to "text" in the element with id elem_id. (Will be added during the INSERT)

**OPTION 2**

```
CREATE TABLE assoc_element_tags (
 elem_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 tag_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 elem_text varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 tag_text varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

If I need the "text", is it better to request for elem_id in `assoc_element_tags` AND another request for text in `element`.

What about a straight forward :

**OPTION 3**

```
CREATE TABLE assoc_element_tags (
 elem_text varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 tag_text varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: The drawback is that you can't establish any relation except `1:1` one. With your first example, you can establish many:many relation. If you think you'll never need anything besides 1:1 relation and if you find it easier to populate a table with two textual columns, then go for it.

Comment: For easier text access you should use a JOIN, otherwise it's wrong because the db is non-normalized

Answer (score 2):

> If I need the "text", is it better to request for elem_id in assoc_element_tags AND another request for text in element

You misunderstand how SQL works.  You would simply be running a *single* query that uses `JOIN` to look up the values in the table.

What are the advantages to the normalized structure?  Here are a few:

- You can declare proper foreign key relationships, so your tag values are protected by the database.
- You can have tags that have no referrals.  For instance, if a user is removed, you don't automatically lose the tags.
- You have a simple list of tags to suggest to users.
- If your tags are longer than a few characters, then your database size may be smaller.

In addition, `JOIN`s in SQL are very efficient, particularly with the use of indexes.  I would advise you to stick with your first three-table solution and learn how to properly query the database.

Comment: Tks, but are you saying that this mysterious `JOIN` command that you don't want to give me will be faster than a `SELECT elem_text FROM assoc_element_tags where tag_id=1;` ? Even if tag_id is the primary key ? OPTION 2

Comment: @bobdylan - you received an excellent answer, and if you ask mr. google about SQL `JOIN`'s - he'll give you plenty of useful answers. Some of them you might even copypaste. Also, a `JOIN` is as mysterious as `SELECT` when it comes to SQL (which means you must update your SQL knowledge asap because it's common and easy to use `JOIN`'s).

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer (Not yours ofc, which is "google it"...). JOIN is awesome i get it, but my question remain and is straight forward : `Which one is the fastest ?`

Comment: @bobdylan - the speed, when it comes to MySQL, boils down to whether MySQL has to look for data on the disk (slow) or if it can cache the working data to RAM (the magic `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting). If MySQL is configured properly, then what you need to focus on is having the data laid out in such a way that it's easy for you to find it. However, if you have a 1:1 relation between those tags or whatever they are, the fastest way would be to store everything in the same table. Speed you'd gain this way wouldn't be anything special, I personally doubt it'd even be in microsecond range.